# Regular expression in Kotlin to find unused variables in code

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have .txt file with Kotlin code where I place few variables.

```
fun main() {
    val unused: Int
    val used = 2
    print(used)
}
```

And I need to write regex to find unused variables in this file. But I get wrong output — `[unused, used]`, but I wanna get `[unused]`. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
fun findUnusedVariables() {
val regex = Regex("(var|val)\\s+([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z])", RegexOption.DOT_MATCHES_ALL)
val text = """
    fun main() {
    val unused: Int
    val used = 2
    print(used)
}
""".trimIndent()

regex.findAll(text).forEach { matchResult ->
    println("[${matchResult.groups[2]?.value}]")
}
}
```

Comment: This regex matches all variable declarations. It doesn't attempt to find usages of those declarations. I think you would need to rethink the approach itself, because with a single regex it might be quite inefficient. Maybe you should do several passes to find usages

Comment: This is not really something that can be done with regex I would think.

Comment: Well it theoretically could, with backreferences and things like that. But that would be cumbersome to write. Probably one pass to find declarations + one pass per variable to find usages would be clearer and not less efficient

Comment: Throw in scope, shadowing, comments, etc. and this quickly approaches impossible.

Comment: It probably needs a full language parser (or most of one). That couldn't be done by a plain regex (which can't even handle arbitrarily-nested structures); it _could_ be done in a Turing-complete superset of regex, but the necessary complexity would almost certainly make it completely impractical for a human to write — and utterly pointless, when there are much more practical alternatives (such as writing your own parser, or even better using the existing one, e.g. via a compiler or IDE plugin).

Answer (score -1):

Regex that need to use — `"val\\s+(\\w+)(?![\\s\\S]*\\b\\1)"`